# jQuery - Dragging/sorting two elements at a time

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working with a somewhat complex contact list manager that involves categories and subcategories. I'm at the point now where I'm trying to implement sorting into the mix. My HTML is as follows:

```
<li>List item</li>
<ul class="subcategory">
     <li>List item</li>
     <li>List item</li>
     <ul class="subcategory">
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
     </ul>
</ul>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
```

Now when a user wants to move a list item, its subcategory should move with it as well (if it has one). So far I've tried `.wrap()`-ing each list item and its subcategory in a div and then making that div sortable, however that wasn't working out so well. Maybe there's a better solution in jQuery for doing it? Maybe my HTML could be structure differently?

Comment: FYI your HTML is invalid. A `<ul>` cannot contain another `<ul>` (it needs to be inside a `<li>`).

Comment: I had a feeling it would come down to my HTML and I didn't even think of how it would validate. Having the `<ul>`'s contained within the `<li>`'s will make the sorting easier too.